# Convert string into very large integer in Hive

Tags: hive, type-conversion, largenumber

I have numeric values stored in a string column named "hst" in a  hive table with 1636626 rows, but to perform arithmetic operations(comparison, difference), I need to convert the hst column into very large integers to preserve all the digits. here's a sample of my data:

```
id    hst
A1    155836976724851034470045871285935636480 
A2    55836976724791053359504802768816491263
B1    55836977111335639658316742086388875264      
A3    55836977111354662261430576153184174079
C2    55836926053814078414548020414090575872     
C4    55836926053833373226361854480885874687
B2    55836926013959368986746057541906857984
B4    55836926013959368635392801615616409599
C3    55836976724870256360155492454040600576
```

I tried decimal type:

```
 SELECT cast('55836976724791053359504802768816491263' as DECIMAL(38, 0))
```

but as the max length of the field is 39 digits and decimal type allows 38 at most it doesn't work for the first value of the sample `155836976724851034470045871285935636480`
Does anyone have an idea how to achieve that ?

Comment: Can you split the data into 2columns ? Each will be bigint which can hold upto 19 char. In total you will get 38 spaces. But i am curious what will be an issue if you store it as string?

Comment: @KoushikRoy the field is already stored in string type and I have to convert it to a mathematical type to do arithmetic operations ( comparison and difference).  Do you think of another way to do that other than splitting it ?

Comment: Hive supports maximum 38 digits length decimal. No very large integers are supported. You have to store it in strings and write you own UDFs for compare and subtract/add

Comment: The UDF will allow to store the field with all its digits(39) or just to perform calculations ? Java/Scala are new to me , do you have any examples of UDFS to start with ? @leftjoin

Comment: UDFs will allow to store it in STRINGs and perform calculations